# Solr 7.7 cant parse hybris 6.7 java double value

Tags: java, upgrade, sap-commerce-cloud, solr5, solr7

I trying to upgrade solr from 5.3(hybris 5.7) to 7.7(hybris 6.7). After start full index from hybris i have NumberFormatException in solr 7.7. Difference that i see, its content-type, 5.3 - application/xml, 7.7 - application/javabin. 5.3 based on content-type uses XmlLoader, and make SolrInputField with correct value like "100.00", but 7.7 uses another loader and value seems like "SolrInputField:fieldname:fieldname=100.00" and takes NumberFormatException when try to parse to double, because "SolrInputField:fieldname:fieldname=100.00" its not double value ofc.
PS. I take solrconfig.xml and solr.xml form 5.3 and upgrade.

UPD: solr 7.7 cant convert BigDecimal

Any ideas, how to fix that?

Comment: You need to use the new solrconfig.xml and schema from solr 7.7